# Magento Database CleanUp

Tags: database, magento

After deleting several StoreViews in order to increase the database performance in several tables are entries of old StoreViews i.e. in `catalog_product_index_eav` are ~4mio. old entries left with store_ids which doesn't exist any more.

Some background information:
We had ~450k products and 21 StoreViews ... way too much. Therefore we splitted the installations and now 400k products and 1 StoreView is left ... but also millions of old entries. It seems Magento doesn't clean delete StoreViews or websites with all unneeded indexes.

Is there any "good" way to clean up the complete database?

Answer (score 2):

After deleting store views delete files fron var/locks and then reindex.
Hope all related entries shall be deleted.